# How to initialize an unnamed structure element within a named union

Tags: c, anonymous-types, unions

I am using a union and an anonymous structure inside it. I want to know how I can initialize the structure members inside it. how can i do that? Please help :)

```
typedef union
{
    uint8_t All;                
    struct
    {
        uint8_t G:1;            
        uint8_t O_B:1;         
        uint8_t Unused:1;       
        uint8_t W1:1;          
        uint8_t W2:1;          
        uint8_t Y1:1;          
        uint8_t Y2:1;           
        uint8_t IAQ:1;          
    };
} _UNION_VARIABLE;

_UNION_VARIABLE bit_field_array[5] = { {.G=1, .O_B=0, ...}, {.G=0, .O_B=1, ...},.....};
```

Is this correct?

Comment: did you try to compile it? what does compiler tell you?

Comment: Also, unnamed bitfield values are just that **no name**: `uint8_t : 1;`

Comment: It worked without issues.